# How to correctly read POST REQUEST body on ESP32?

Tags: c++, http, arduino, esp32

I am trying to create server and client interaction on Microcontroller ESP32. It'll consist of simple HTTP server and a client. So the client will send a `POST` request to the server, and the server will do some logic with the data it received.

And for more context, here is the server-side code:

```c
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {


            int contentLength = header.indexOf("Content-Length: ");
              if (contentLength != -1) {
                contentLength = header.substring(contentLength + 16).toInt();
                int bodyRead = 0;
                  while (bodyRead < contentLength && client.available()) {
                      char c = client.read();
                      requestBody += c;
                      bodyRead++;
                  }
              }

              // Separate direction and vehicle id
              int sd = requestBody.indexOf('=');
              int vd = requestBody.indexOf('&');

              String direction = requestBody.substring(sd + 1, vd);

              int pos = requestBody.indexOf('=', vd);

              String vehicle = requestBody.substring(pos + 1);
       
              // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
              // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
              client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
              client.println("Content-type:text/html");
              client.println("Connection: close");
              client.println("Got it, " + direction + " for : " + vehicle);
              client.println();
              Serial.println("Request Body : " + requestBody);
              Serial.println("Direction : " + direction);
              Serial.println("Vehicle : " + vehicle);
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
```

And here is the client-side code:

```c
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      WiFiClient client;
      HTTPClient http;
    
      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(client, serverName);
      
      // Specify content-type header
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      // Data to send with HTTP POST
      String httpRequestData = "from=south&id=military";           
      // Send HTTP POST request
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);
     
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        
      // Free resources
      http.end();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
```

Now, the problem is the server cannot correctly read the `POST` request.

And before I tested the client, I use API Tester (mobile application) to test the server, and it works as expected. So my server prints these out in the serial monitor:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: apitester.org Android/7.5(641)
accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 22
Host: 192.168.4.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip

Request Body : from=south&id=military
Direction : south
Vehicle : military
Client disconnected.
```

But when I send the `POST` request from a client, my server doesn't return any data on the serial monitor:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
User-Agent: ESP32HTTPClient
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1,chunked;q=0.1,*;q=0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 23

Request Body : 
Direction : 
Vehicle : 
Client disconnected.
```

I still haven't figured out why this happens. I guess the mistake is on the client side? Because the server works when used with API Tester. But from many tutorials I have read, my client code should be working correctly.

Also, because there is not something like an error code, I don't know from where I should fix this issue. I hope you can help me with this.

[EDIT]:

```
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // Serial.print("STATUS REPORT <header> : ");
            // Serial.println(header);

            // Find the Content-Length header
            int contentLength = header.indexOf("Content-Length: ");
            if (contentLength != -1) {
              Serial.print("STATUS REPORT <contentLength> : ");
              Serial.println(contentLength);
              // Find the end of the Content-Length line
              int endOfContentLength = header.indexOf("\r\n", contentLength);
              Serial.print("STATUS REPORT <endOfContentLength> : ");
              Serial.println(endOfContentLength);
              if (endOfContentLength != -1) {
                // Extract the Content-Length value as an integer
                contentLength = header.substring(contentLength + 16, endOfContentLength).toInt();
                int bodyRead = 0;
                while (bodyRead < contentLength && client.available()) {
                  if (client.available()) {
                    char c = client.read();
                    requestBody += c;
                    bodyRead++;
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            // Separate direction and vehicle id
            int sd = requestBody.indexOf('=');
            int vd = requestBody.indexOf('&');

            String direction = requestBody.substring(sd + 1, vd);

            int pos = requestBody.indexOf('=', vd);

            String vehicle = requestBody.substring(pos + 1);
     
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/plain");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            client.println("Got it, " + direction + " for : " + vehicle);
            Serial.println("Request Body : " + requestBody);
            Serial.println("Direction : " + direction);
            Serial.println("Vehicle : " + vehicle);
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is when you are extracting the `Content-Length` value from your `header`, you are expecting `Content-Length` to be the last HTTP header stored in the `header`, but it is not the case in your example.

The reason you are making that assumption is because when you are calling `substring()` to grab the `Content-Length`'s integer value, you are extracting *everything* that immediately follows `"Content-Length: "` all the way to the *end* of the `header`.  So, that only works when `Content-Length` is the last HTTP header.

You need to instead stop extracting the integer value at the `'\r'` or `'\n'` character that actually ends the `Content-Length` line.  Which means you need to specify an end index when you call `substring()`.

But, you are not storing either of those characters in your `header`, so you can't find them when you need them.

---

Also, be aware that HTTP headers are *case-insensitive*, and that whitespace is *optional* following the `':'` character after a header name.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to modify the code based on your suggestion.

Comment: I've update my code as per your suggestion and found no error when compiling. But the server still doesn't catch the request.